# How to change the config for CKEditor 5 in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor5

I have added the config as per another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57268877/4723985

However, I am encountering an issue:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/cards/CreateCard.js
  Line 59:22:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

  57 |             editor={ClassicEditor}
  58 |             config={
> 59 |               toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ]
     |                      ^
  60 |             }
  61 |             data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
  62 |             onInit={editor => {
```

Below is the relevant portion of ReactJS component:

```
            editor={ClassicEditor}
            config={  
              toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ]
            }
            data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
            onInit={editor => {
              // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
              console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor);
            }}
            onChange={(event, editor) => {
              const data = editor.getData();
              console.log({ event, editor, data });
            }}
            onBlur={(event, editor) => {
              console.log("Blur.", editor);
            }}
            onFocus={(event, editor) => {
              console.log("Focus.", editor);
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything inside the a JSX expression needs to be valid javascript. Keeping this in mind, let's look at the `config` prop:

```
config={
  toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ] 
}
```

Inside the `{}`, the content is:

```
toolbar: []
```

which isn't valid javascript at all. What you are looking for is an object with toolbar property.
To solve this, you can refractor to:

```
config={{
  toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ]
}}
```

Comment: It solved the issue. Thanks for the detailed explanation.